# Prove $\iint_\mathbb{D} \bar{\partial}f(z)(\zeta-z)^{-2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\pi (f'(\zeta)-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, quasiconformal-maps

When I read the paper *Teichmuller spaces and BMOA* by K. Astala and M. Zinsmeister, I am stuck in the following eqution for a long time.
$$\iint_\mathbb{D} \bar{\partial}f(z)(\zeta-z)^{-2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\pi (f'(\zeta)-1)$$
where $f=z+\dfrac {b_1}{z}+\cdots$.

It seems the equation is kind of related to [Cauchy-Pompeiu’s Formula](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~ckfong/S32.pdf), but I have no idea how to get that $1$. I think $\bar{\partial}f(z)$ means $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}$, I am not very sure since the author didn't give the definition.

I put the original paper here, obviously the third equation omits a minus. Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: that one comes from the residue at infinity (by Green's theorem the area integral is more or less the same - up to some $i$ factor - as the integral of $\frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^2}$ on the unit circle since $\bar \partial$ cancels in the denominator as that is analytic everywhere except at $z=\zeta$ which cannot happen inside the unit disc, and then we use the residue theorem or basic computations like Cauchy in a (degenerate) annulus, though one has to be careful as we are in the outer part of the circle including $\infty$ so the signs have to be considered carefully

Comment: Green's theorem complex version is that with suitable smoothness of $f$ on a domain $G$, the area integral on $G$ of $\partial_{\bar z} f$ is $\frac{1}{2i}$ the integral of $fdz$ on the boundary and above we, of course, apply it to $\frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^2}$ on the unit disc and then we use that outside the unit disc $\frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^2}$ is complex analytic with poles at $\zeta, \infty$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your comment! I did not think of residue's theorem and I worked it out now.

Comment: Excellent - it is standard stuff so useful to do it by hand a few times